# The IF statement is ignoring or not accepting the logical operator 'or'

Tags: python, if-statement

```
# asks the question and gives the choices   
choice=input('what is your favourite colour? press 1 for red, 2 for blue, 3 for yellow or 4 to quit') 
# if the responder responds with choice 1 or 2,3,4 it will print this
if choice=='1' or 'one':
    print('red means anger') 

elif choice=='2'or 'two':
    print('blue represents calmness')
elif choice=='3' or 'three':
    print('yellow represents happiness')
elif choice=='4' or 'four':
    print('it was nice meeting you. goodbye.')
else:
    print('sorry incorrect answer please try again.')
```

> One of my students wrote this and I can't seem to get it working.
>   HELP! It keeps repeating red means anger. If I comment out the 'or',
>   it works but why can't she use 'or'? I want her to add a loop but only
>   if this works first.

Comment: Your or statement is being intepret as (choice==1) or 'one') ,  evaluate 'one' is always true

Comment: Which language is this? Visual Basic.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have statement like

```
if choice=='1' or 'one':
```

it will be treated as

```
if (choice=='1') or 'one':
```

'one' is always evaluate to True, thus the if condition is always fulfill, what you need is as below, bracket to make things clearer

```
if (choice=='1') or (choice=='one'):
```

Alternatively, when you have multiple OR statement to be check against a value, can consider put all the check value in a list and use in like below, this look cleaner to me when the value to check increasing

```
if choice in ['1', 'one', '2', 'two', '3', 'three']:
```

Comment: @David Schwartz, thanks for pointing that out, added some explanation to original question though its already answer by DivingTraube,  suggest the later as alternative

Answer (score 3):

The `or` is not used correctly. You need to write

```
choice == '1' or choice == 'one'
```

Otherwise type coercion will evaluate 'one' to true and the `or` condition of the first if statement is always `true` (a *tautology*) and the other cases are never checked.

Comment: Thank you. Early beginnings in Python and I am understanding how to debug!